# Removing item in list during loop

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have the code below. I'm trying to remove two strings from lists `predict strings` and `test strings` if one of them has been found in the other. The issue is that I have to split up each of them and check if there is a "portion" of one string inside the other. If there is then I just say there is a match and then delete both strings from the list so they are no longer iterated over.

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I get the above error though and I am assuming this is because I can't delete the string from test_strings since it is being iterated over? Is there a way around this?

Thanks

```
    for test_string in test_strings[:]:
        for predict_string in predict_strings[:]:
            split_string = predict_string.split('/')
            for string in split_string:
                if (split_string in test_string):
                    no_matches = no_matches + 1
                    # Found match so remove both
                    test_strings.remove(test_string)
                    predict_strings.remove(predict_string)
```

Example input:

```
test_strings = ['hello/there', 'what/is/up', 'yo/do/di/doodle', 'ding/dong/darn']
predict_strings =['hello/there/mister', 'interesting/what/that/is']
```

so I want there to be a match between hello/there and hello/there/mister and for them to be removed from the list when doing the next comparison.

After one iteration I expect it to be:

```
test_strings == ['what/is/up', 'yo/do/di/doodle', 'ding/dong/darn']
predict_strings == ['interesting/what/that/is']
```

After the second iteration I expect it to be:

```
test_strings == ['yo/do/di/doodle', 'ding/dong/darn']
predict_strings == []
```

Comment: *Yawn* Please provide 1) example input; 2) expected output

Answer (score 1):

You should never try to modify an iterable while you're iterating over it, which is still effectively what you're trying to do. Make a `set` to keep track of your matches, then remove those elements at the end.

Also, your line `for string in split_string:` isn't really doing anything. You're not using the variable `string`. Either remove that loop, or change your code so that you're using `string`.

You can use augmented assignment to increase the value of `no_matches`.

```
no_matches = 0

found_in_test = set()
found_in_predict = set()

for test_string in test_strings:
    test_set = set(test_string.split("/"))
    for predict_string in predict_strings:
        split_strings = set(predict_string.split("/"))
        if not split_strings.isdisjoint(test_set):
            no_matches += 1
            found_in_test.add(test_string)
            found_in_predict.add(predict_string)

for element in found_in_test:
    test_strings.remove(element)

for element in found_in_predict:
    predict_strings.remove(element)
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution let a string from predict_string match with multiple test_strings even after it's already matched with one?

Comment: Possibly. If you show us what you expect the output from your example input to be it would help us figure out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, I've included them now.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why have we split test_set as well? From what I can understand, split_strings.isdisjoint(test_set) will just return a boolean so can you tell me how it deals with the repeating problem? :/ I'm just a bit confused!

Comment: You say that you want a match between `'hello/there'`, and `'hello/there/mister'`. But you've also turned `'hello/there/mister'` into a list: `['hello', 'there', 'mister']`. What you want to do is figure out if there's any overlap between `'hello/there'` and `['hello', 'there', 'mister']`. So because you've split `predict_string` you must also split `test_string`. Now, you can't do a comparison between to lists to see if they have any elements in common. You can do that with a set though. So you check to see if there's any overlap between the two sets. If there is, remove both elements.

Comment: Right but aren't I just looking for "hello" in "hello/there" which should just return a match straight away? I'm doing a string comparison at that point no?

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems likely that two `split_string`s match the same `test_string`. The first time through the loop removes `test_string`, the second time tries to do so but can't, since it's already removed!

You can try `break`ing out of the inner `for` loop if it finds a match, or use `any` instead.

```
for test_string, predict_string in itertools.product(test_strings[:], predict_strings[:]):
    if any(s in test_string for s in predict_string.split('/')):
        no_matches += 1  # isn't this counter-intuitive?
        test_strings.remove(test_string)
        predict_strings.remove(predict_string)
```

Comment: Great, thanks I'll give it a go. Why do you see the no_matches+=1 as counter intuitive? Also, could you clarify what exactly any() is doing here.

Comment: Your code reads: "If we find a match, increment the counter 'no_matches'." That doesn't make sense without context, but maybe it's fine in context. I'd expect "If we find a match, remove stuff. Else, increment 'no_matches'." `any` evaluates each expression in an iterator and returns `True` if any of them are truthy, or `False` if all of them are falsey. We're constructing a generator of `s in test_string` iterating `for s in predict_string.split('/')`

Comment: @tryingtolearn I can't reproduce your error with the sample data you provided and my code here. I end up with `test_strings == ['yo/do/di/doodle', 'ding/dong/darn']` and `predict_strings == []`

Comment: Do you think we could move this over to chat quickly?